# Как прочитать сразу нессколько страниц

Tags: java

```
public static String URL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=743b8194cfdd5e009a3264a5813d2a6d&page=" + page(5);

private static int page(int a) {
    int z = 0;
    int u;
    for( u = 1; u <= a; u++ ) {
        System.out.println(z = u);
    }
    System.out.println(z);
    return z;
}
```

Comment: Добрый день, есть ссылка URL, надо спарсить 5 страниц, я сделал метод page с циклом, но когда делаю return, возвращается только последняя  пятая страница. Надо чтобы возврщало все страницы согласно циклу

Comment: Вы не понимаете видимо кк работает цикл и ключевое слово return. Почитайте пару статей об этом повнимательней и станет понятно. Это распространённая ошибка среди новичков в программировании

Answer (score 0):

Все правильно у вас возвращает. Вы передаете в процедуру переменную а = 5. Прогоняете цикл 5 раз, в котором фактически выполняется действие z = z + 1. И затем как результат возвращаете z = 5.

Для того что бы получить то что вы хотите, вам необходимо что то наподобие следующего:

```
for(int u = 1; u <= a; u++){
        parserURL(URL + u);  // передаем в процедуру парсинга URL страницы
    }
```

Если же вам нужен именно перечень номеров вида[1,2,3,4,5], воспользуйтесь обычным массивом или ArrayList